# Rich Text Field Editor height issue in PowerApps form

Tags: sharepoint-online, rich-text, powerapps-forms

We have a rich text editor field in the Power apps form. That rich text field is connected to the sharepoint rich text column. If we click on the item in the SharePoint list view, the power apps form opens properly, but some times the Rich text field height decreased to up to the height similar to the format tool bar of the Rich text editor control.

Please find the attached the error for the same as well.

Kindly help me on this

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. RTF in a powerapps form, pointing to a rich text field in a sharepoint database. Seemingly RANDOMLY, will not show the text box the correct size, only showing the header of the RTF entry box. Often a refresh on the browser window or closing/opening the browser again, it will load correctly. Its as if the module for the RTF, is not loading correctly sometimes. Height for the text box is FIXED (not dynamic, or a max/min value or anything like that for re sizing), so nothing that should be causing to load smaller. The rest of the form loads all in the correct siz

Comment: This is fixed as below.
Added one separate expand icon on the top right section of the rich text field and then added code to change height of the rich text control on click of the icon